Custom function for Mongoose is throwing an error
We have a type code for Moongose
import { Model, Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

const studentSchema: Schema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        class: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

studentSchema.methods.methodName = function() {
    return this.name + '!!!';
};

const Student = model("Student", studentSchema);

export default Student;

As you can see, there is a custom method called methodName. When I use.'
const s = new Student({
    name: "Chris",
    class: "1",
});

s.methodName();

Im getting an error that says:

's.methodName' is of type 'unknown'.ts(18046)

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance for help.

Did you define the method in the schema like they way in official doc?
